# Tagging custom open graph objects in photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging

Can I tag something else other than user in a photo?
I want to create custom open graph objects which will be taggable on facebook photos.
If not is there any plan on facebook api to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag people in open graph stories too. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople